# "yield" return different type?

Tags: c#, interface

Let's say we have the following code:

```
public IEnumerator FirstTest()
{
   yield return 1;
}

public IEnumerable SecondTest()
{
    yield return 1;
}
```

I know the code has no logic, but it is valid, so how come "yield" can return different type, FirstTest return an IEnumerator, SecondTest return an IEnumerable? There is no inheritance relationship between IEnumerator and IEnumerable

Comment: Don't forget that compiler is smart. There is obvious and simple, and generic solution to get `IEnumerable` out of `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 7):

Both are valid according to [C# Language definition of `yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

> The declaration of an iterator must meet the following requirements:
>
> The return type must be `IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator, or
>   IEnumerator<T>`.
>
> The declaration can't have any in ref or out parameters.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator function can return an Enumerable, an IEnumerable, an IEnumerator, or an IEnumerator. The relationship between the interfaces does not matter here, as this is a language feature.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield),

> The declaration of an iterator must meet the following requirements:
>
> - The return type must be IEnumerable, IEnumerable, IEnumerator, or IEnumerator.
> - The declaration can't have any in ref or out parameters.